# showing that this theta series is holomorphic

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Consider the theta series $$f(w)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}e^{\pi i(n+w)^2z}$$for fixed $z\in \mathbb{H}$. Then f(w) is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}.$
Let $z=x+iy,y>0,w=u+iv$ then $$|e^{\pi i(n+w)^2z}|=e^{-(n^2y+2n(uy+vx)+u^2y+2uvx-v^2y)}. $$
Can I  use then $ n^2y+2n(uy+vx)+u^2y+2uvx-v^2y>n^2y/2$ for $n\geq n_0$,
so that I can estimate this series by the geometric series to finally use the weierstrass m-test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use your estimate. However, since the sum is over all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ you need it for $\lvert n\rvert \geqslant n_0$, not only for $n \geqslant n_0$. The value $n_0$ cannot be chosen independently of $w$, but for every $R > 0$ it can be chosen such that the inequality holds uniformly for all $w$ with $\lvert w\rvert \leqslant R$. And we can also let $z$ vary in the upper half-plane, for every compact $K \subset \mathbb{H}$ and every $R > 0$ there is an $n_0$ and a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$\bigl\lvert e^{\pi i(n+w)^2z}\bigr\rvert \leqslant e^{-n^2\delta}$$
holds for all $\lvert n\rvert \geqslant n_0$ and all $z \in K$, $\lvert w\rvert \leqslant R$.

Thus by the Weierstraß $M$-test the series converges absolutely and locally uniformly on $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{H}$, and
$$g(w,z) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{\pi i(n+w)^2z}$$
is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{H}$.

Comment: thanks for your help. Does w also vary in K? For your estimate, did you use $ n^2y+2n(uy+vx)+u^2y+2uvx-v^2y >n^2 \delta $, for $|n| \geq n_0$ and because $u,v,x,y$ are bounded ?

Comment: $w$ varies in some bounded subset of $\mathbb{C}$. I chose the discs with centre $0$, but other choices work just as well. We can't restrict $w$ to the same set as $z$ because $z$ is confined to the upper half-plane, whereas $w$ can be in the lower half-plane. Yes, the estimate uses the above inequality, which with upper bounds for $\lvert u\rvert, \lvert v\rvert, \lvert x\rvert, y$ becomes $n^2y + 2n\ldots \geqslant n^2 y - \lvert n\rvert B - C$, and with a lower bound for $y$, say $y \geqslant 2\delta$ for $y \in K$ that becomes $\ldots > n^2 \delta$ for sufficiently large $\lvert n\rvert$.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help.